# JavaScript - How to empty the input field when it value has been updated to " " in a click event callback function

Tags: javascript

So here is my code

```
<button class="btn-new"><i class="ion-ios-plus-outline"></i>New game</button>
<button class="btn-roll"><i class="ion-ios-loop"></i>Roll dice</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Target" class="target">

document.querySelector('button.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var input = document.querySelector('.target').value;
    if(input){
        var winningScore = input
    }else {
        winningScore = 100;
    }
document.querySelector('.btn-new').addEventListener('click',function(e,input){
    input = '';
  })
})
```

I am assigning the value entered in the input field to a variable when user clicks on roll dice button and trying to empty the input field making it " " when the user clicks on new game button. This doesn't throw an error but I am still able to see the value even when I click the new game button. I also see the input field getting emptied when I write it as `document.querySelector('.target').value = ' ';` 
but doesn't work  when I write it just using the variable name `input = '';`.

Can someone please tell me whats the mistake in the code here ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just setting the value of your `input` variable, which has no effect on the DOM element. To set its value, use `document.querySelector('.target').value = ""` (just like you did when reading the value). Or consider only doing the query once:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.target');
var input = el.value;
// ...
el.value = "";
```

Separately, event handlers don't get passed a second argument, so no need for the `input` parameter on your event handler callback.

Also, even though the `var` in `var winningScore` will take effect for the entire function (thanks to `var` hoisting), it's poor practice to declare it in one branch and not the other; instead, just declare it at the top.

You can also replace that `if`/`else` with

```
winningScore = input || 100;
```

...if you like, and since that means we only use `input` in one place, we don't need it anymore.

Finally, you're adding a new event listener to `.btn-new` **every time** `button.btn-roll` is clicked. It seems unlikely to me you want to do that.

Taking all of that into account:

```
document.querySelector('button.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var el = document.querySelector('.target');
    var winningScore = el.value || 100;
    // ...presumably use `winningScore` here...
});
document.querySelector('.btn-new').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.querySelector('.target').value = '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> This doesn't throw an error but I am still able to see the value
> even when I click the new game button
>
> Can someone please tell me whats the mistake in the code here ?.

Setting your `input` (coming as a parameter) to `''` **will change its type from `HTMLInputElement` to `String`**, and it **won't be referring to the `input` element anymore** and it won't set its `value` property to `""`

You need to do

```
document.querySelector('.btn-new').addEventListener('click',function(e,input){
 input.value = ''; //referring to the input passed as a parameter
})
```

Here **you are also creating a new event-listener on every click on `button.btn-roll`**, you need to move the `addEventListener` on `.btn-new` out

```
var input = document.querySelector('.target');
document.querySelector('button.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(input.value){
        var winningScore = input.value
    }else {
        winningScore = 100;
    }
})  
document.querySelector('.btn-new').addEventListener('click',function( ){
    input.value = '';
})
```